# [a b]=cholcov function returns a=[] and b=NaN for a symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, decomposition

I have this matrix:

```
S=   6.84370358358718e-006    -7.45833473076585e-007
    -7.45833473076565e-007     7.11723106043725e-006
```

It is symmetric:

```
S-S'=                     0    -2.00111533788828e-020
      2.00111533788828e-020                         0
```

and is positive definite:

```
eig(S)= 6.22219831321029e-006    and     7.73873633081414e-006
```

When I use `[a b]=cholcov(S)`, it returns returns `a=[]` and `b=NaN`. It is written in MatLab help that`[T,num] = cholcov(SIGMA)` ... `If SIGMA is not square and symmetric, num is NaN and T is empty.`

Of course the `chol(S)` function decomposes this function without any error. I  don't know the difference between `chol` and `cholcov` and it is not important, since I don't have any choices. The error comes from `mvnrnd(zeros(1,2),S)` function, when I try to generate some random numbers:

`??? Error using ==> mvnrnd at 118

SIGMA must be a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix.`

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote:

```
S-S'=                     0    -2.00111533788828e-020
      2.00111533788828e-020                         0
```

That says that S is *not* symmetric.  It's ALMOST symmetric.  But... not quite.  If this is due to numerics, you might be able to fix this with:

```
symmetricS = mean(cat(3,S,S'),3);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought Matlab considers e-20 zero!

Answer (score 4):

It is NEARLY symmetric. You yourself admit that it is NOT symmetric. Is being ALMOST pregnant the same thing as pregnant? You show that S~=S'. The fix is easy.

```
S = (S + S')/2;
```